# Cannot render blob as image in grails 2.1

Tags: image, grails, controller, render

I'm trying to render an uploaded image from a gsp without success. I have this to render the image.. What is wrong?

```
//domain-class
class Something {
    ...
    byte[] image
}

//controller
def displayImage(){
    def something = Something.get(id)
    response.contentType = 'image/jpeg'
    response.outputStream << something?.image
    response.outputStream.flush()
}

//gsp
<img src="${createLink(action:'displayImage',  id:something?.id)}" />
```

I've modified the controller to be like this

```
displayImage(){
    def something = Something.get(params.id)
    ........
}
```

I don't get an exception but neither get the image displayed. I don't know if this has something to do with the ContentType or any other thing that i have to specify. Any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

You need to go with either of the below approaches:

```
def displayImage(){
    def something = Something.get(params.id)
    ........
}
```

or

```
def displayImage(Long id){
    .....
}
```

Controller has `params` bind automatically instead of `id`. If you get an exception after having this modification as well, then please add that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
def displayImage(){
def something = Something.get( params.id )
byte[] image = something.image
response.outputStream << image
}
```

Comment: please look at http://fbflex.wordpress.com/2008/04/22/image-uploading-in-grails-with-5-lines-of-code/

Answer (score 0):

```
def displayImage(){
    Photo photo = Photo.get(1)
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=${photo?.name}")
    response.contentType = photo?.type
    response.outputStream << new File(photo?.path).getBytes()
    response.outputStream.flush()
    return;
}
```